# Sorting flat tree

Tags: php, mysql, tree

I have a table with tree structure, with lvl, lft and rgt columns.
Initially I had flat tree with `SELECT * FROM tree_table ORDER BY lft ASC` to get it sorted by position in tree.
But now I have `sort` column to sort nodes on theirs levels. How can I get tree sorted by it position in tree and it weight at same time?
I think it is impossible with MySQL query but how can I get it with PHP?

Table data example ordered by `lft`

```
id | lft | rgt | level | sort
1 | 1 | 628 | 1 | 0
2 | 2 | 281 | 2 | 3
3 | 3 | 128 | 3 | 0
4 | 4 | 15 | 4 | 1
5 | 16 | 27 | 4 | 5
....
```

Without `sort` column I display rows in the same order, but now I want get this:

```
id | lft | rgt | level | sort
1 | 1 | 628 | 1 | 0
2 | 2 | 281 | 2 | 3
3 | 3 | 128 | 3 | 0
5 | 16 | 27 | 4 | 5
4 | 4 | 15 | 4 | 1
....
```

Comment: You're going to need to give us some data and/or code to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Well, given your example you can get your desired result with:

```
SELECT * FROM tree_table ORDER BY level, Sort DESC
```

But I may be misunderstanding your question a bit.

Comment: With this query only top nodes will be sorted, but not their childrens.

Comment: @nucleartux I guess I just am not understanding how the data you are providing represents a tree. I recommend http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/ for dealing with hierarchies in MySQL though. Maybe that will help you accomplish your goal